# restar datos de horas en minutos

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Quiero restar dos campos TIME en mi consulta en minutos, esta es la consulta:

```
select distinct r.dni, r.fecha, c.entrada,r.horaentrada, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,c.entrada,r.horaentrada) as Diferencia
from Cronograma c
inner join RegistroES r
on c.dni=r.dni
where r.fecha = '2019-09-21'
```

Pero me da la resta incorrecta ya que estan en formato de 12 horas, deseo que este en formato 24 horas para que me de la resta correcta.

gracias

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con "está en formato de 12 horas". Datediff devuelve un entero, el cual no tiene formato...

Comment: te explico, c.entrada y c.hora entrada estan en formato de 12 horas, es decir si el primero tiene 12:30:00 pm y el segundo tiene 1:00:00 pm me sale la resta del date diff -30 cuando deberia salir solo 30. es decir no diferencia si es am o pm

Comment: Y cómo hiciste para que la columna sea en formato 12 horas? Puedes publicar la definición de tu tabla?

Comment: Según [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) y [este otro](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-time/) la hora va de 00 a 23, y los minutos de 00 a 59. Necesito ver cómo creaste la tabla y cómo insertas registros para averiguar qué podrá estar pasando en tu código.

Comment: Si la diferencia es negativa y la quieres positiva, no es cuestión del formato sino del orden de las horas.